# Fermat Numbers are pairwise coprime $\implies$ infinitely many primes

Tags: prime-numbers

**Given** that the Fermat numbers $F_m$ are pairwise relatively prime.

**Prove** that there are infinitely many primes.

Comment: So, each Fermat number is either prime or is divisible by a unique prime number which does not divide any other Fermat number

Comment: Let $p_m$ be the smallest prime divisor of $F_m$. Since the $F_k$ are pairwise relatively prime, the $p_m$ are distinct. So the set of all $p_m$ is infinite. (The relative primality is not hard to prove, but it looks as if you are not expected to give  a proof.)

Comment: @AndréNicolas If I wanted to prove its primality how would I be able to prove it?

Comment: Let $m\lt n$. Note that $2^n=(2^m)^{n-m}$ So if $x=F_m$ then $F_n=(x-1)^{2^{n-m}}+1$. Using the binomial theorem to expand, we find that $x$ divides $F_{n}-2$. So any divisor $d$ of $F_m$ divides $F_n-2$. If $d$ also divides $F_n$, then $d$ divides $2$. But $d$ is odd, so $d=1$. (You will find variant proofs on MSE, the question has been asked repeatedly. Answers are likely to be less terse than this comment.)

Comment: @AndréNicolas. For answers on MSE see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107942/fermat-numbers-proof). So the OP already knows it.

Comment: @AlexisDailey: I assumed your "prove its primality" was intended to mean relative primality. We do not need to identify the smallest prime factor of $F_m$ to know there is one. But if you are looking for efficient algorithms, there are methods for Fermat numbers that are much more efficient than the "general" methods for numbers of the same size.